# Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-9

I updated my project from laravel 8 to laravel 9 then I tried to make a test case generated by artisan.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class SimpleTest extends TestCase
{
 /**
  * A basic feature test example.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function test_example()
 {
     $response = $this->get('/');

     $response->assertStatus(200);
 }
}
```

But when I run phpunit I always get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Tests\TestCase" not found in path/to/SimpleTest.php:9
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @knubbe yeah did that several times, still got the error

Comment: Can you click on that class or is there that class in that namespace?

Comment: make sure if test namespace included in composer json within psr4 autoload-dev

Comment: @EsmailShabayek yes i have included test in autoload-dev ``` "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
                "Tests\\": "tests/"
           },
           "classmap": [
               "tests/TestCase.php",
               "tests"
           ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created fresh Laravel 9 app to investigate this case.
Apparently the content of TestCase.php in my app was different from the one in fresh app. So I replace TestCase.php file with the one from fresh app and it works now.